# Laravel Vue.js Heroku [vite:load-fallback] Could not load '' (imported by '') ": ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ''

Tags: laravel, vue.js, heroku, vite, inertiajs

I'm trying to deploy my Laravel Vue.js project (with Inertia.js) on [heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps).

But when it executes `vite build` it gives this error:

```
-----> Build

       Running build

       

       > build

       > vite build

       

       vite v3.1.1 building for production...

       transforming...

       ✓ 90 modules transformed.

[vite:load-fallback] Could not load /resources/js/Components/Modals/FormModal.vue (imported by resources/js/Pages/Admin/Classrooms/Modals/CreateClassroomModal.vue): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/resources/js/Components/Modals/FormModal.vue'

error during build:

Error: Could not load /resources/js/Components/Modals/FormModal.vue (imported by resources/js/Pages/Admin/Classrooms/Modals/CreateClassroomModal.vue): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/resources/js/Components/Modals/FormModal.vue'

-----> Build failed

       

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:

       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:

       https://help.heroku.com/

       

       Love,

       Heroku

       

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.

 !     Push failed
```

I've already tried to set the node.js version in the `package.json` to the same version that I use locally (16.x), but still gives this error.

In the `CreateClassroomModal.vue` file the import looks like this:

```
import FormModal from "@/Components/Modals/FormModal.vue";
```

And the file `/resources/js/Components/Modals/FormModal.vue` really exists in the project.

When I try to compile everything locally (with `npm run build`) everything works fine and there are no errors.
What causes the problem that my resources can't be compiled?

Comment: I think this has to do with the `@` symbol and/or that Heroku runs on Linux server. Locally I use windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I've fixed the problem.**

The problem was that on Github the folder names was `/resources/js/components/...` and locally `/resources/js/Components/...` (with a uppercase). I don't know how this ever happened, but it's fixed